# MBA to 2 HP monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have macbook air ( 2014) and I want to connect 2 27" HP Monitors. I have thunderbolt to HDMi converter and then also bought HDMI splitter but it only mirrors the monitor. If I buy USB to HDMI converters, would that setup work or no?

Comment: You can't use USB to power a monitor.

Answer (score 1):

According to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-1.7-11-early-2014-specs.html)

> *Although Apple only reports that this model can support a single external display up to 2560x1600, Intel reports that this model can
>   simultaneously support two external displays up to 2560x1600 "daisy
>   chained" via Thunderbolt.

So, no - only one monitor over HDMI. Two If you can daisy-chain compatible Thunderbolt monitors.